# How can I show that a lattice $(S, \leq)$ must have a greatest element?

Tags: lattice-orders

How can I show that a lattice $(S, \leq)$, where $S$ is a finite set, must have a greatest element? What I mean is an element $x$ such that $a \leq x$ for all $a \in S$.

Comment: By using the definition of a lattice, and what that says about the join of two elements of a lattice.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Based on the definition of a lattice it can be shown that - if a lattice $S$ has no greatest element - for every $a\in S$ there will exist some $b\in S$ with $a\leq b$ and $a\neq b$.

Now observe that this cannot occur in a *finite* lattice.

Answer (score 1):

You can build the greatest element by induction.

If the lattice has $1$ element, of course the property is trivial.

Suppose you have a maximum for lattices with $n$ elements. Then take a lattice with $n+1$ elements $\{x_0,...,x_n\}$. By hypothesis of induction $$a = x_0 \vee ... \vee x_{n-1} $$ exists. Then $$a \vee x_n$$ is the greatest element of your lattice.

Comment: Since I can't access my original account Clara S (I've been trying for very long now and contacted the staff), I'll have to comment this way. @C.Dubussy I have been told that a problem with your solution is that you can't be sure that a = x0 V ... V xn-1 is still a lattice at that time, if you what I mean. Do you have any further suggestions to your solution?

Comment: Isn't that obvious that if $\{x_0,..x_n\}$ is a lattice then $\{x_0,..x_{n-1}\}$ is also a lattice ? If you just write the definition, it will be clear.

Comment: I know, but I've been told I'm not allowed to do that by my teacher. It might sound weird! What if the {x0,..xn} is not a lattice?